# Lyx - how to Insert hyperlink of file

Tags: file, hyperlink, lyx

The Insert> Hyperlink File option does not appear to work in LyX Version 2.1.0beta1.

Any attempt at inserting a full file specification in  the Target box comes up with the message "Unknown parameter name"

I was trying to insert a .webm video in a link. The video resides in the same directory.

Thanks in advance

samar

Comment: If this is a regression (i.e. it worked in a previous version of LyX) then please open a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: It also works in in LyX 2.1.1